# how would you explain the motions in the solar system?

Tags: observational-astronomy, the-sun, galaxy, solar-system, milky-way

like so i don't get it it does not make sense I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly?

Motions are governed by the Law of Universal Attraction (or Gravitation), which states that the force between two objects is proportional to their mass and inversely proportional to the square of their distance. In other words, “heavier” objects will attract more, but distant objects will attract less.

This in turns gives rise to the three laws of planetary movement of Johannes Kepler (which he formulated between 1609 and 1619):

• All orbits are ellipses, with the “parent” body (the Sun for planets; planets for satellites) being in one of the foci of the ellipse;

• The time it takes a body to circle its parent body is inversely proportional to the distance from which it is from the parent body;

• The imaginary line between the parent body and the “child” body covers equal areas in equal times.

So, to sum everything up: Planets revolve around the Sun in ellipses (“stretched circles”); the closer they are, the faster they move. Satellites revolve around planets in the same way.

Hope it clears things up a little.

Next time, please try to be more precise in your questions. I answered it this time because I believe everyone has a right to know and there are no dumb questions, but your question was very vague…